# Escrever no ficheiro txt gravar, ler e gravar num em outro ficheiro txt

Tags: java, txt

Comecei a trabalhar a pouco tem num empresa que programa os cartões MiFire e estou na fase experimental. Entretanto o engenheiro mandou.me fazer um trabalho.

Primeira etapa:

Tenho que introduzir dois valores numéricos e obter o resultado da soma;
Guardar num ficheiro sequencial as parcelas e o resultado da soma;
Cada linha de ficheiro guardado "f1" contem 3 informações:

```
 linha1<- p1, p2, soma
 linha2<- p1, p2, soma
```

Segunda etapa:

Ler o ficheiro guardado e mostrar as parcelas com elemento de uma multiplicação e obter o resultado.
Gravar num ficheiro txt "f2" os elementos e o produto em cada uma das linha.

Estou a tentar fazer mas só que nao estou a conseguir, alguém podia me ajudar??

```
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(txtN1.getText());
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(txtN2.getText());
        int soma = n1 + n2;
        //int mult = n1 * n2;
        txtR.setText(Integer.toString(soma));
        //txtRM.setText(Integer.toString(mult));

        String linhat = "";

        //Ler e gravar no primeiro arquivo

        File arq = new File("arquivo.txt");


        try{

        arq.createNewFile();

        FileReader ler = new FileReader(arq);

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(arq);
        BufferedWriter escrever = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        linhat = Integer.toString(n1)+ ";";
        escrever.write(linhat);

        linhat = Integer.toString(n2)+";";
        escrever.write(linhat); 

        linhat = Integer.toString(soma) ;
        escrever.write(linhat);


        PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq);
        gravarArq.print(linhat);


        escrever.close();
        fileWriter.close();


        BufferedReader lerb = new BufferedReader(ler);

        String linha = lerb.readLine();

        while(linha !=null){
            System.out.println(linha);
            linha = lerb.readLine();

    //ler o ficheiro       
      File file = new File("arquivo.txt");
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
      // gravar o ficheiro "f2"
      File file = new File("arquivo2.txt");
      FileWriter fw = new FileWrite(file);
      BufferedReader bw = new BufferedReader(fw);

      String s ="",
      bw.newLine;
      bw.write(s);
      bw.flush();



           /* Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("arquivo.txt"));
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nexteLine();
            System.out.println(line);
       */

        }
        }catch (IOException ex){
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi corretamente o seu problema. Veja se essa solução atende:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class TxtHandler {

    private Path pathSoma;
    private Path pathMultiplicacao;

    public TxtHandler(Path pathSoma, Path pathMultiplicacao) {
        super();
        this.pathSoma = pathSoma;
        this.pathMultiplicacao = pathMultiplicacao;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        //Diretório que o arquivo será escrito
        URI dir = TxtHandler.class.getResource(".").toURI();
        //arquivo que será usado para colocar os valores somados
        Path pathSoma = Paths.get(dir).resolve("arquivoSoma.txt");
        //aquivo que será usado para colocar os valores multiplicados
        Path pathMultiplicacao = Paths.get(dir).resolve("arquivoMultiplicacao.txt");

        TxtHandler txtHandler = new TxtHandler(pathSoma, pathMultiplicacao);
     // passa os dois valores que deseja somar e multiplicar. O método irá somar e salvar no arquivo
        txtHandler.salvarESomar(3, 6);
        // ler do arquivo salvo anteriormente, multiplica os valores e salva em outro arquivo
        txtHandler.lerMultiplicarESalvar();
    }

    public void salvarESomar(int n1, int n2) throws IOException {
        int soma = n1+n2;
        //O StringJoiner serve para concatenar valores utilizador um delimitador específico
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(";");
        joiner.add(String.valueOf(n1)).add(String.valueOf(n2)).add(String.valueOf(soma));

        List <String> linhas = Arrays.asList(joiner.toString());
        //Esse método recebe o caminho do arquivo, o conteúdo a ser escrito através de uma lista de strings e
        //de que maneira o arquivo será manipulado. Nesse caso a opção CREATE signfica que se o arquivo não existir,
        //ele será criado. A opção APPEND irá adicionar o conteúdo sempre no final do arquivo.
        // 
        Files.write(pathSoma, linhas, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }

    private String getLinha(int n1, int n2, int result) {
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(";");
        joiner.add(String.valueOf(n1)).add(String.valueOf(n2)).add(String.valueOf(result));
        return joiner.toString();
    }

    public void lerMultiplicarESalvar() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        List<String> linhas = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathSoma.toString()))) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] itens = line.split(";");
                int n1 = Integer.parseInt(itens[0]);
                int n2 = Integer.parseInt(itens[1]);
                int multiplicacao = n1*n2;
                linhas.add(getLinha(n1, n2, multiplicacao));
            }
        }
        Files.write(pathMultiplicacao, linhas, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    }

}
```